# How to wait for a value until it performs the next syntax in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I am obtaining height data from my sensor and here is my code:

```
If Sensor1 = 5 Or Sensor1 = 6 Or Sensor1 = 7 Then
   If Sensor1 >= 13 Then
      flagCtr1 = 1
   End If
ElseIf Sensor1 = 8 Or Sensor1 = 9 Then
   If Sensor1 >= 13 Then
      flagCtr1 = 2
   EndIf
ElseIf Sensor1 = 10 Then
   If Sensor1 >= 13 Then
      flagCtr1 = 3
   End If
End If
```

Basically what I want to happen is, for example, when my sensor detected the height 7, it will wait for the value greater than or equal 13 before it performs the flagCtr = 1. I tested this code and nothing happens.

This is my dilemma. This is an example of how I read the height where 15 is the height where there is no object placed below the sensor

15
15
15
7 - object was placed
7
7
7
7
8 - object is being removed
15
15
15

everytime I will remove the object it goes to a certain number that is also in one of the conditions. My problem is the latest height data is being read not the data that was read at a time interval. So what I want to do is that I will wait for the sensor to go back to the value greater than or equal 13 before it performs the next instruction.

It's like this, if I detected 7 I want to disregard the other values I read and wait for value that is >=13

Sorry for a long post, I really need help, this is my thesis. Thank you so much

**EDIT1:**

how i read my data from my sensors

```
AxWinsock1.GetData(strData)
for ctr = 0 To UBound(strData)
tstring = tstring + Chr(strData(ctr))
If DisconnectF1=0 Then
If tstring Like "*DATA_*_OK*" Then
Dim parsedStr() As String = Split(tsring,"_")
Sensor1 = parsedSTR(1) : Sensor2 = parsedSTR(2)
Sensor3 = parsedSTR(3) : Sensor4 = parsedSTR(4)
```

this what my arduino sends me:
DATA_15_15_15_15_OK

**EDIT2:**

For those who still have problems with the correct solution just make previousState global.

Comment: Show how you read the values. If everything executes on the same thread, then it is natural that your code doesn't do anything (e.g. if `Sensor1` is 10, it cannot be >= 13). If it is not on the same thread, you will have race conditions.

Comment: hi sir edited my post

Comment: This is a perfect use case for a state machine. I would recommend reading a few articles about this concept. What does `flagCtr1` represent and how do you use it? I have the feeling that there might be a better option for that.

Comment: I used flagCtr1 just to store the constant where it leads to a specific syntax to perform

Comment: That might also be a candidate to integrate in the state machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current if statement doesn't make sense since this

```
If Sensor1 = 5 Or Sensor1 = 6 Or Sensor1 = 7 Then
   If Sensor1 >= 13 Then
```

Assume that the variable Sensor1 can be both below and above 12 at the same time.

What you need to do is keep track of the previous sensor.

```
If PreviousSensor1 = 5 Or PreviousSensor1 = 6 Or PreviousSensor1 = 7 Then
   If Sensor1 >= 13 Then
      flagCtr1 = 1
   End If
ElseIf PreviousSensor1 = 8 Or PreviousSensor1 = 9 Then
   If Sensor1 >= 13 Then
      flagCtr1 = 2
   EndIf
ElseIf PreviousSensor1 = 10 Then
   If Sensor1 >= 13 Then
      flagCtr1 = 3
   End If
End If

PreviousSensor1 = Sensor1
```

EDIT

Since you want to ignore values until you hit 13. You could keep the flag value and set it when you hit >= 13. PreviousState would be set to 0 as default and kept in between calls.

```
If PreviousState = 0 Then
   If Sensor1 = 5 Or Sensor1 = 6 Or Sensor1 = 7 Then
      PreviousState = 1
   ElseIf Sensor1 = 8 Or Sensor1 = 9 Then
      PreviousState = 2
   ElseIf Sensor1 = 10 Then
      PreviousState = 3
   End If
Else
   If Sensor1 >= 13 Then
      flagCtr1 = PreviousState
      PreviousState = 0
   End If
End If
```

Here's an example.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim state As Integer = 0
        Dim sensorData() As Integer = {15, 15, 15, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 15, 15, 15}

        For Each data As Integer In sensorData
            state = ProcessSensor(state, data)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

    Public Function ProcessSensor(ByVal state As Integer, ByVal sensor1 As Integer)

        If state = 0 Then
            If sensor1 = 5 Or sensor1 = 6 Or sensor1 = 7 Then
                state = 1
            ElseIf sensor1 = 8 Or sensor1 = 9 Then
                state = 2
            ElseIf sensor1 = 10 Then
                state = 3
            End If
        Else
            If sensor1 >= 13 Then
                'flagCtr1 = previousState
                Console.WriteLine("Set flagCtr1 to {0}", state)
                state = 0
            End If
        End If

        Return state
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Not quite. If `Sensor1` is `5`, then the code should wait until it becomes `13` and then set `flagCtrl` to `1`. If the sensor value increases by `1` every time, this will not happen with your code. Actually, nothing would happen when `Sensor1` reaches `13` because `PreviousSensor1` will be `12`.

Comment: I thought about this but what's wrong with this is that when my sensor reads 7: previousSensor1 will be 7, but when I remove the object it reads 8 then previousSensor1 will be replaced by 8 so Im back to square one.

To make things simpler this is what I want to happen:
Read 7, wait for the value 13 and above then do flagCtr1 = 1. Upon reading the value 7, the values 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 will be disregarded.

Comment: @the_lotus sir i debugged the code via breakpoint because nothing was happening, it is not going through the Else... it is not checking if Sensor1 >= 13 :(

Comment: @the_lotus having the PreviousState = 1 and the checking of PreviousState is on top of it (by line), how is it going to check if the PreviousState is 0 or not?

Comment: @MichaelZ I just added an example.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH MAN! Analyzed everything and the logic I wanted to happen worked! @the_lotus